# How to perform a check if Rails 5 cache is enabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 there is a possibility to enable/disable cache:

```
rails dev:cache
=> Development mode is now being cached.

rails dev:cache
=> Development mode is no longer being cached.
```

My question is, is there a method from which the application can get the information if the cache is enabled or disabled?
Something like: `Rails.cache.enabled?`

I know that I can check the existence of file `tmp/caching-dev.txt`, however I'm looking for something higher level.

Comment: Running rake dev:cache will create or remove tmp/caching-dev.txt. When this file exists `config.action_controller.perform_caching` will be set to `true` in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Original issue : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18875
PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20961/files

Comment: Thx. That's what I was looking for. I'll use it like: `Rails.configuration.action_controller.perform_caching`. Can you post it as an answer (instead of comment)?

Comment: Welcome. There is already an answer on this question. It will be updated there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When cache is enabled, the cache_store in rails config mustn't be :null_store, so we can easily check with:

```
Rails.application.config.cache_store != :null_store
```

=> true means cache is enabled

Or we can check directly with `perform_caching` flag: (Thanks @AjinkyaPisal)

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.perform_caching
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `config.action_controller.perform_caching` 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html